# Как рекурсивно переделать список в массив?

Tags: c, рекурсия

Нужно **написать функцию**, которая принимает одним параметром адрес начала списка а возвращает адрес массива целых длиною на 1 больше списка и в первый елемент массива заносит длину этого массива.

Я написал эту функцию с циклами. Покажите, как можно создать такую же функцию применяя только рекурсию?

Вот моя функция:

```
int *list_to_array(struct list_elem *list)
{
        enum {max_array_size = 128};
        int len = 0;
        struct list_elem *tmp = list;
//Подсчет количества елементов списка:
        while( tmp ){
                len++;
                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if(len+1 > max_array_size){
                puts("list is too long");
                return NULL;
        }

//Создание массива и его заполнение:
        int *array;
        array = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(int));
        *array = len;
        for(int i = 1; i <= len; i++){
                *(array+i) = list->data;
                list = list->next;
        }
        return array;
}
```

Comment: Рекурсивно вычислить длину списка умеете?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если для этого написать еще одну функцию, которая возвращает целое, а не указатель на него, то да - умею. Но задача такова, что функция (одна) принимает один параметр - указатель на структуру (список), и возвращает указатель на целое (массив).

Comment: Нельзя использовать в решении несколько рекурсивных функций? Надо обойтись одной?

Comment: Рекурсия, это учебное задание такое? В реальности проще наращивать массив realloc-ом по мере продвижения по списку

Comment: @avp Да, задание учебное. В реализации нельзя пользоватися ```realloc```. Суть задания в том, чтобы сделать функцию, которая принимает единственный параметр - список, а возвращает указатель на массив.

Comment: Как с одним аргументом (без внешней переменной с размером списка) сделать такую рекурсию не знаю. С двумя аргументми -- `int *list_to_array (list_item *e, int   list_size);` -- в принципе, понятно. Вызываете -- `int *arr = list_to_array(list, 0);` Внутри делаете рекурсивный вызов -- `a = list_to_array(list->next, list_size + 1);`, если `list != 0`. Когда дошли до 0 в list_size будет размер списка. Надо вызвать malloc,  положить в нулевой элемент массива list_size и вернуть массив. Соответственно, во всех рекурсивных возвратах надо класть в массив (с конца) значения из списка. Вроде все.

Comment: Согласен с @avp - при такой постановке вопроса нет информации сколько памяти выделять под массив, если не использовать внешние переменные. А список не содержит информации о своем размере?

Comment: @DmitryK, да, если ограничиться одной функцией. Если же предложенную в задании считать обвязкой, то можно очень просто -- `int *list_to_array (list_elem *list) { return list_to_array2(list, 0); }` / вот и LISP вспомнил -)

Comment: @avp Но это вариации на тему переменной в которой запомнить размер массива. Что глобальная переменная, что возврат значения через параметр функции - смысл-то один и тот же - где-то надо считать и запоминать размер списка, чтобы выделить память под массив.  Опять-таки если нельзя пользоваться реаллоком - нужно заранее знать размер, чтобы выделить точный объем памяти.

Comment: @DmitryK, поместить размер в начало массива -- это из ТЗ в  вопросе. Вы что-то все же упустили,  размер заранее знать не нужно. Мы его узнаем, дойдя до конца списка (в этот момент в стеке у нас (в виде сохраненных аргументов) находятся указатели на все элементы списка). Вот тут мы и делаем malloc-ом массив. А по ходу  раскрутки из всех рекурсивных вызовов заполняем его от конца к началу

Comment: Хорошая задача. Добавлю что любую программу можно записать в виде одной рекурсивной функции с фиксированным набором параметров. Так-то.

Comment: @avp Да так я и думал сделать, вот только как реализовать подсчет этих самых указателей на елементы списка?

Comment: @VektorValentine, увелиличиваете на 1 при каждом рекурсивном вызове -- `a = list_to_array(list->next, list_size + 1);`  / Впрочем, в ответе вам написали другой (полностью отвечающий вашему заданию) вариант (со статической переменной). Он правильно работает, поскольку (это из описания языка С) **инициализация** (именно инициализция (почитайте подробнее в книжке)) статической переменной происходит **ровно один раз**. При всех последующих вызовах это действие не проводится и ее значение остается тем же, что было при выходе из функции

Comment: @avp То что надо! Спасибо. "Глобальные и статические переменные инициализируюся один раз в начале программы. Локальные переменные инициализируются **каждый** раз, при входе в блок. Статические локальные переменные инициализируются **один** раз при входе в блок."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз нельзя передавать дополнительную информацию через параметры функции, будем хранить их в статических переменных. Например накопленную длину списка:

```
int *list_to_array(struct list_elem *list) {
    static int length = 0;
    int *array;
    if (list == NULL) {
        array = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(int));
        array[0] = length;
    } else {
        ++length;
        array = list_to_array(list->next);
        --length;
        array[length + 1] = list->data;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Ну тогда опять никакой разницы. Логически что статическая переменная, что глобальная переменная, что передача переменной через ещё один параметр в функцию для подсчета длины списка - одно и то же.

Comment: Объясните, почему на втором рекурсивном вызове, переменная ```length``` не затирается новым значением, ведь при втором вызове функция опять начинается со слов ```static int length = 0```. Как так, что при провереке она равна нулю только при первом вызове функции???

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, Спасибо Вам. Я никак не мог найти решение. Оно и понятно, ведь я не осознавал, как работают статические переменные.

Comment: Статики инициализируются один раз при первом вызове функции. В дальнейшем `= 0` не работает. Синтаксис сбивает с толку, да.